# can you debug auto vectorized loops?

Tags: c++, vectorization, sse, simd, avx2

I'm working on a codebase that has a lot of SIMD intrinsic code. Now that we have AVX2, we still need to have SIMD code that runs on non-AVX2 capable processors, which will be significantly more work. Plus those 128bit lane crossing limitations for AVX2 shuffles also complicates things. For these reasons, it's a good time to rely more on auto vectorization. The main things that scare me are the prospect of a single innocent change killing the parallelism and the prospect of debugging auto-vectorized code in case there is a problem.

I've compiled the following with g++ -O1 -g -ftree-vectorize and attempted to step through with GDB  (does anyone know why -ftree-vectorize doesn't work with -O0 ?)

```
float a[1000], b[1000], c[1000];
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
    c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
  return 0;
}
```

but don't get any meaningful results. For example sometimes the value for i says <optimized out> while other times it jumps by 20.

It seems the main problem is that it's difficult to map the SIMD state to the original C state for debugging. But realistically, can it be done?

Comment: Why do you want to debug it? If you want to verify that it gets vectorized, wouldn't it be better to, inspect the assembly code or run benchmarks (at full optimization settings)? If you want to find a bug, debug the non-vectorized (and otherwise non-optimized) version.

Comment: Yeah, compiler bugs are nasty when and if they happen. I don't know if a (source level) debugger is the right tool to approach it, but in any case, I understand.

Comment: So, far debugging for errors is mostly hypothetical. I definitely remember submitting a bug in the Visual C++ 2010 vectorizer that caused it to improperly fuse an unaligned load with an arithmetic instruction into a single x86 instruction, causing it to crash when run on a non-aligned array.

Comment: I'm more interested in understanding how efficient the vectorized code is, which is very difficult from the assembly code. This is made worse when multiple verions of the code are generated (some to handle SIMD remainders or unaligned parts, some to deal with aliased arrays, etc). If I can step through the loop in GDB 4, 8, or 16 at a time, and see the corresponding assembly code side by side, that could help some with understanding.                       Actually, what I really want is a source-to-source compiler that rewrites your code with vector types and operators. Is there such a thing?

Comment: I don't think there is a compiler that will give you C-like vectorized output, though you might give LLVM IR (through Clang) a shot. I find LLVM IR easier to inspect by hand than real assembly. (LLVM's vectorizer is comparatively young, but apparently it already works quite well.) Anyway, for performance, stepping through the code seems prone to misleading results to me. For example, you won't see any indicator on cache utilization or pipeline behaviour. If you want to determine performance, **benchmark** and profile.

Comment: With gcc, `-fdump-tree-optimized` produces a file with a C-like syntax that shows what optimizations were performed.

Answer (score 0):

Using a debugger on auto-vectorized code is tricky, esp. when you want to inspect variables that need to behave differently (e.g. the loop counter).

You can either use a debug build (`-O0` or `-Og`), or you can understand how the compiler vectorized the code, and examine registers asm and registers.  Depending on what kind of bug you need to track down, you might or might not have a problem with an auto-vectorized build.

It sounds from the comments like you're more interested in checking the efficiency of the auto-vectorization, rather than actually debugging to fix logic bugs in your code.  Looking at the asm, and benchmarks, is probably your best bet.  (even a simple `rdtsc` before/after a call, or in a unit-test that tests performance as well as correctness.)

Sometimes the compiler will generate multiple versions of a loop, e.g. for the case where the input arrays overlap, and for the case where they don't.  Single-stepping (by instruction, with `stepi`, with `layout asm` in gdb) can help, until you find the loop that actually does most of the work.   Then you can focus on just how it's vectorized.  If you want to eliminate the checks and alternate versions, `restrict` pointers can be helpful.  There's also `p = __builtin_assume_aligned(p, 16)`.

You could also use [Intel's free code analyzer](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-architecture-code-analyzer) to attempt to statically analyze how many cycles an iteration takes.  Put IACA marks at the top of your loop body and after the closing paren of your loop, and hope GCC puts them in appropriate places in the auto-vectorized loop, and that the inline asm doesn't break auto-vectorizing.

No optimization answer would be complete with a link to http://agner.org/optimize/, so here you go.